# g++: error: unrecognized command line option

Tags: gcc, swig

```
swig -c++ -python cords.i
g++ -c -O3 -fPIC -std=c++11 -fopenmp cords.cpp cords_wrap.cxx -/home/zkx/.conda/envs/baseline/python3.7m
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-/home/zkx/.conda/envs/baseline/python3.7m’
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

I have download SWIG, and Ubuntu 18.04, GCC 7.5.0

Makefile:

```make
compile:
    swig -c++ -python cords.i
    g++ -c -O3 -fPIC -std=c++11 -fopenmp cords.cpp cords_wrap.cxx -/home/zkx/.conda/envs/baseline/python3.7m
    g++ -shared -O3 -std=c++11 -fopenmp -Wl,-soname,_cords.so -o _cords.so cords.o cords_wrap.o
    swig -c++ -python shrink_cpp.i
    g++ -c -O3 -fPIC -std=c++11 -fopenmp shrink_cpp.cpp shrink_cpp_wrap.cxx -/home/zkx/.conda/envs/baseline/python3.7m
    g++ -shared -O3 -std=c++11 -fopenmp -Wl,-soname,_shrink_cpp.so -o _shrink_cpp.so shrink_cpp.o shrink_cpp_wrap.o

clean:
    rm *.o *.so *.cxx cords.py shrink_cpp.py
```

It is like https://github.com/tjluyao/iris_demo/blob/main/src/Makefile

Comment: The linked Makefile has no option that is anything like `-/home/zkx/.conda/envs/baseline/python3.7m`. Where does that option come from? What it is supposed to do?

Comment: The closest I think of, is that you want to use an include flag. In that case, try using `-I/home/zkx/.conda/envs/baseline/python3.7m`.

Comment: Generally, if you are creating your own Makefile and own compiler commands, you should definitely look up and read up on the various compiler flags, and understand what they do. Just blindly copy-pasting and adjusting other Makefiles and compiler commands may not end well.

Comment: NB: if you really downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 (and installed it), you may consider using a more recent LTS version, like 22.04. Ubuntu 18.04 is not supported anymore (at least the unpaid version). So I assume you use 18.04 because that is the system you have to work with, not a system you installed recently.